Как что то делать вне слотов в qt?
Решил попробовать поработать в Qt. Изучил минимальную базу, и дальше решил идти пробовать(и учиться) на практике. Давно хотел портировать свою приложуху, которую написал на MIT app inventor, на пк, вот и решил этим заняться, вот только я начал что то делать, и столкнулся с проблемой:
В начале проги, я хочу вызвать метом isconnectpossible, где проверю, есть ли вообще какой то блютуз модуль на компе, однако, я хочу его вызвать после загрузки интерфейса, вот как это сделать?
Я сначало попробовал закинуть вызов метода в main.cpp, но он почему то не хочет работать, я уже сижу 3 часа над этим, help please.
Сори, если этот вопрос тупой, но в инете внятного ответа я не нашёл. Не бульте пожалуйста)
main.cpp:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, &a, SLOT(isconnectpossible()));
    VoiceHome w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

voicehome.cpp:
#include "voicehome.h"
#include "ui_voicehome.h"

#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QBluetoothLocalDevice>

VoiceHome::VoiceHome(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::VoiceHome)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

VoiceHome::~VoiceHome()
{
    delete ui;
}



void VoiceHome::isconnectpossible()
{
    QMessageBox::question(this, "Нет возможных устройств!", "VoiceHome не нашёл устройства bluetooth. Попробовать переподключиться?",
                                                                          QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    /*try {
        QList <QBluetoothHostInfo> listofbluetoothdevices = QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices();
        if(listofbluetoothdevices.size() > 0){

        }
        else{
            QMessageBox::StandardButton reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Нет возможных устройств!", "VoiceHome не нашёл устройства bluetooth. Попробовать переподключиться?",
                                                                      QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
            if(reply == QMessageBox::Yes){
                isconnectpossible();
                return;
            }
            else{
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (QBluetoothLocalDevice::Error error) {
        QMessageBox::about(this, "error", "error");
    } */
}


Ваш вопрос станет нормальным после добавления кода...

какой код добавить?

"В начале проги, я хочу вызвать метом isconnectpossible..."

добавил в вопрос

Это называется "загрузить функцию на выполнение в event loop". Можно сделать, например через QTimer::singleShot:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, &app, [] { isconnectpossible(); } );
    ...
    return app.exec();
}


О, это кажется прям то, что я искал, попробую, отпишусь

странно, не работает, почему то не вызывает слот

Убери SLOT() и увидишь ошибку в написании слота. SLOT() это устаревший способ записи, он превращает содержимое в строку и не даёт компилятору возможности проверить имя функции.

Use of undeclared identifier 'isconnectpossible' пишет так

и не даёт скомпилить

.pro файл надо добавить тогда на рассмотрение тоже чтобы понять забыли ли вы включить свои заголовки в код.
SOURCES += \
    voicehome.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    ui_voicehome.cpp

HEADERS += \
    voicehome.hpp \
    ui_voicehome.h

FORMS += \
    ui_voicehome.ui

В вашем mаin.cpp
#include "ui_voicehome.h"
#include 

Скорее нужен ещё и #include "voicehome.hpp" или .h в мейне чтобы использовать.

Ваш вызов isconnectpossible является методом класса, чтобы вызвать нужен объект класса соответственно.

а как сделать обьект класса?

main.cpp:

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    VoiceHome w;
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, &a, SLOT(w.isconnectpossible()));
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

Либо
QTimer::singleShot(3000, &a, SLOT(isconnectpossible()));


По идее VoiceHome w;
Должен быть объявлен раньше QTimer::singleShot

Возможно даже
QTimer::singleShot(3000, [&w]() {
    w.isconnectpossible();
});


Или как в его обьяснении QTimer::singleShot(0, &app, [] { w.isconnectpossible(); } );

Это уже вопросы в области неизученных основ С++, и к первоначальному вопросу отношения не имеет.
